# What is the schema type "CreativeWork"?

Tags: schema.org

What is the Schema type "CreativeWork"?

Does "CreativeWork" refer to an entity (e.g a published tangible paper book or ebook listed or reviewed in a bookseller's page) whose main content is separate from the Webpage? Or can the main content of that work be an integral part of the page and the page and that content be one and the same and thus the page itself becoming that "CreativeWork"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the page and the book are creative works that could have separate markup.  Even a portion of a web page can be a creative work (`WebPageElement`).

I would suggest using the `Book` schema and not using the `WebSite`, `WebPage`, `WebContent` or `WebPageElement` schema.   Google gives a rich snippet for books, but doesn't have any special treatment for web content.  See [the Google's structured data search gallery](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/search-gallery).

The only benefit to implementing structured data is when Google shows your site differently in the search results because of it.  Google only does so for a small subset of schema.  There is very little reason to use any other schema.  There is no general SEO benefit to using structured data.  See my blog: [SEO Myth: Structured data helps search engine rankings](https://blog.ostermiller.org/structured-data-seo/).

From https://schema.org/CreativeWork:

> The most generic kind of creative work, including books, movies, photographs, software programs, etc.
>
> ...
>
> #### More specific Types:
>
> - [AmpStory](https://schema.org/AmpStory)
> - [ArchiveComponent](https://schema.org/ArchiveComponent)
> - [Article](https://schema.org/Article)
> - [Atlas](https://schema.org/Atlas)
> - [Blog](https://schema.org/Blog)
> - [Book](https://schema.org/Book)
> - [Chapter](https://schema.org/Chapter)
> - [Claim](https://schema.org/Claim)
> - [Clip](https://schema.org/Clip)
> - [Collection](https://schema.org/Collection)
> - [ComicStory](https://schema.org/ComicStory)
> - [Comment](https://schema.org/Comment)
> - [Conversation](https://schema.org/Conversation)
> - [Course](https://schema.org/Course)
> - [CreativeWorkSeason](https://schema.org/CreativeWorkSeason)
> - [CreativeWorkSeries](https://schema.org/CreativeWorkSeries)
> - [DataCatalog](https://schema.org/DataCatalog)
> - [Dataset](https://schema.org/Dataset)
> - [DefinedTermSet](https://schema.org/DefinedTermSet)
> - [Diet](https://schema.org/Diet)
> - [DigitalDocument](https://schema.org/DigitalDocument)
> - [Drawing](https://schema.org/Drawing)
> - [EducationalOccupationalCredential](https://schema.org/EducationalOccupationalCredential)
> - [Episode](https://schema.org/Episode)
> - [ExercisePlan](https://schema.org/ExercisePlan)
> - [Game](https://schema.org/Game)
> - [Guide](https://schema.org/Guide)
> - [HowTo](https://schema.org/HowTo)
> - [HowToDirection](https://schema.org/HowToDirection)
> - [HowToSection](https://schema.org/HowToSection)
> - [HowToStep](https://schema.org/HowToStep)
> - [HowToTip](https://schema.org/HowToTip)
> - [HyperToc](https://schema.org/HyperToc)
> - [HyperTocEntry](https://schema.org/HyperTocEntry)
> - [LearningResource](https://schema.org/LearningResource)
> - [Legislation](https://schema.org/Legislation)
> - [Manuscript](https://schema.org/Manuscript)
> - [Map](https://schema.org/Map)
> - [MathSolver](https://schema.org/MathSolver)
> - [MediaObject](https://schema.org/MediaObject)
> - [MediaReviewItem](https://schema.org/MediaReviewItem)
> - [Menu](https://schema.org/Menu)
> - [MenuSection](https://schema.org/MenuSection)
> - [Message](https://schema.org/Message)
> - [Movie](https://schema.org/Movie)
> - [MusicComposition](https://schema.org/MusicComposition)
> - [MusicPlaylist](https://schema.org/MusicPlaylist)
> - [MusicRecording](https://schema.org/MusicRecording)
> - [Painting](https://schema.org/Painting)
> - [Photograph](https://schema.org/Photograph)
> - [Play](https://schema.org/Play)
> - [Poster](https://schema.org/Poster)
> - [PublicationIssue](https://schema.org/PublicationIssue)
> - [PublicationVolume](https://schema.org/PublicationVolume)
> - [Quotation](https://schema.org/Quotation)
> - [Review](https://schema.org/Review)
> - [Sculpture](https://schema.org/Sculpture)
> - [SheetMusic](https://schema.org/SheetMusic)
> - [ShortStory](https://schema.org/ShortStory)
> - [SoftwareApplication](https://schema.org/SoftwareApplication)
> - [SoftwareSourceCode](https://schema.org/SoftwareSourceCode)
> - [SpecialAnnouncement](https://schema.org/SpecialAnnouncement)
> - [Statement](https://schema.org/Statement)
> - [TVSeason](https://schema.org/TVSeason)
> - [TVSeries](https://schema.org/TVSeries)
> - [Thesis](https://schema.org/Thesis)
> - [VisualArtwork](https://schema.org/VisualArtwork)
> - [WebContent](https://schema.org/WebContent)
> - [WebPage](https://schema.org/WebPage)
> - [WebPageElement](https://schema.org/WebPageElement)
> - [WebSite](https://schema.org/WebSite)

Answer (score 1):

"The most generic kind of creative work, including books, movies, photographs, software programs, etc." from https://schema.org/CreativeWork

The answer to your question is "both".  A creative work could be an entire web page (a discussion about the art of Monet) or it could be a component of a web page (a photo of a work by Monet) and even both at the same time.

Keep in mind that rights to the ownership of a creative work might be what determines which part of a bigger creative work belongs to who.

Comment: By the way, can the same thing be said about an ebook, which I guess is also a part of CreativeWork? For example, if I publish a book (on any subject) entirely in my own website instead of as a normal book or ebook (in epub etc), can the page/s be tagged as "EBook" as per schema?